# How do I acknowledge client-side ( android app) that data has been done processing by GCP cloud functions?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create an app that lets a user upload a picture to the cloud storage and cloud functions return a file/ or JSON response after processing the user uploaded picture.

Here is a whole process in a nutshell:
Users upload the data -> data uploaded to cloud storage-> processed by cloud functions-> result exported to cloud storage/ or return JSON response to the user end device (app)

The next step is to download the data (or get JSON response) on the client-side once it has been processed and exported to cloud storage.

My main issue here is, How should I acknowledge client-side (app) that data has been done processing in cloud functions side?

What services should I use here? I am restricted to using GCP cloud functions (python environment).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Server application cannot send *requests* to a client application with the standard HTTP/HTTPS protocols. To achieve what you want, you need a socket connection between the server and the client, so the server will be able to send data to the client at any time.

**Solution 1**

If possible, you can use firebase [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database) which will do the socket connection for you:

When the cloud function finishes processing the data, it writes the response to a specific node in realtime database (the response may contain the uploaded data URL if you want to download it on the client side).

You can refer [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to setup firebase admin sdk for your server app in your preferred language (python is supported), and to [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) to get started. This [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) will show you how to **save data** on realtime db.

On the client side, you [listen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data) to changes on that specific node to get the cloud function response (whenever the cloud function writes a response in realtime DB, your client will receive the written data).

**Solution 2**

You can use [Cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging) to send silent/data-only notification to your client app when your function finishes its job.

**Solution 3**

You can use a python WebSocket library for your server app and a android WebSocket library for your client app. (but I don't recommend you this third solution)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, how do I achieve this task
 "when the cloud function finishes processing the data, it writes the response to a specific node in realtime database". I  am using python runtime in cloud functions, Is there any library that let me "write the response to a specific node in realtime database"?

Comment: I have updated my answer with some links that will show your how to set up firebase realtime db for python server app and how to write data to the db.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I have accepted your answer and +1.